# Precision error in numpy.var

Tags: numpy, numerical-methods, floating-point-precision, variance

I am trying the following code for estimating the variance in a sample, and compare it to the numpy.var implementation.

```
import numpy as np

def rcov(xj, (i, Mi, Si)):
        j  = i + 1
        Mj = Mi + (xj - Mi) / j
        Sj = Si + (i/j) * (xj - Mi) ** 2
        return (j, Mj, Sj)

def mycov(X):
        s = (0., 0, 0)
        for i in xrange(len(X)):
                s = rcov(X[i], s)
        return s[-1] / (len(X) - 1) # sample covariance

X = np.random.rand(1000000)
N = 1e+15

print
print 'Sample (co)variance with 1 dof.'
print '-------------------------------'
print 'np.var(X)     ', np.var(X, ddof=1)
print 'mycov(X)      ', mycov(X)
print 'np.var(X+N)   ', np.var(X+N, ddof=1)
print 'mycov(X+N)    ', mycov(X+N)
```

And the output is

```
Sample (co)variance with 1 dof.
-------------------------------
np.var(X)      0.0833039106062
mycov(X)       0.0833039106062
np.var(X+N)    19208514.2744
mycov(X+N)     0.0859324294763
```

raising two questions:

1. would it help if I upgrade to numpy 1.8? I am currently on 1.6.1
2. numpy is a numerical library. why does it fail at a simple numerical problem?

Comment: numpy 1.9 implements a more accurate sum for 1d array which improves the result a bit (I get 0.22) but it does currently not implement a numerically robust algorithm for the variance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of speed, NumPy does not check for arithmetic overflow or underflow. It's the user's responsibility to choose dtypes which are large enough to maintain the desired level of precision throughout all computations.

Using NumPy 1.8, and selecting `X` to be of dtype `longdouble`, rather than the default `float64`,

```
X = np.random.rand(1000000).astype('longdouble')
```

yields

```
Sample (co)variance with 1 dof.
-------------------------------
np.var(X)      0.0832200737104
mycov(X)       0.0832200737104
np.var(X+N)    0.0832200805148
mycov(X+N)     0.0832199500372
```

Comment: it is better to use the name `np.longdouble`. `float96` is only available on systems where the long double is 12 bytes long. On most 64 bit systems it is 16 bytes long and thus named `float128`. The accuracy is only 80 bits in any case (if the platform provides this at all). There is currently no numpy support for real IEEE quads.

Comment: Thanks. I can work with that. Though it is hard to see what precision is required for the numpy internals (this error is specific to their implementation, as far as I can tell).